# Why are L-functions called such?

Tags: terminology, l-functions

L-functions are discussed here: http://www.lmfdb.org/intro/tutorial...

So why are they called L-functions...?

Is there a reason for the L?

Comment: I believe that the $L$-functions are named after Peter Gustav Lejeune Dirichlet. There are different types of $L$-functions, but I believe that they all relate to the Dirichlet $L$-functions.

Comment: The choice of *name* was by Dirichlet. But I do not know why he chose that name.